# Invoking a method exactly once across multiple jars

Tags: java

I have a method that is invoked every time my jar is deployed, is there a way I make sure that method is invoked once if multiple jars are deployed on different instances?

P.S

I have thought of running that method via REST Endpoint through Jenkins.
One approach can be reading a variable from Database as it is common across servers.
Other approach can be putting environment variable in one of the server instance.

Is there a way to do it via code or other approach?

Comment: Can you give more details? I can not understand what you are trying to achieve exactly